# chassis external sata X-dock (HDD Dock) use for an OS installation

Tags: windows, hard-drive, case

My case have a external sata X-dock (HDD Dock) that, I suppose, could be used to working with a new HDD whitout to open the case side panel.

I would unconnect my primary HD (Western Digital 1TB SATAII 64MB), where is located my OS, connect a new HD on this sata X-dock, install the OS (Windows XP Professional Version 2002 sp3) and all the apps i need (Office, browser, Photoshop, games, etc.) in the new HD (Samsung 320Gb F4 7200rpm 16MB SATA II). After that, the Western Digital become the second HD (for Archive) after formatting partition C (where now is the OS and the apps) and the Samsung become the primary HD whit the OS (obiviously i will move theSamsung to the interior of the case).

the question:
Is possible, after unconnetting my primary HD, do an OS installation on a new HD using a external sata X-dock ?

**My system:**

- AMD Phenom II X4 955 Black Box 125W
- Asus M4A785TD-M EVO
- Radeon HD5770 1GB GDDR5 Asus
- CoolerMaster GX 650W
- G.Skill 2x2GB PC3-12800 1600Mhz-787 4GBECO
- Western Digital 1TB SATAII 64MB
- CoolerMaster cm690 II Advanced Tower Black
- 3 x Enermax Everest 120mm Blue Led

Answer (score 1):

- **Yes** its possible to do an installation on a HD using external SATA dock.

Comment: I think the question is if windows will still boot after he connects it to the internal connector, or if the new OS drive will have to remain on the external.

Comment: that ("the new OS drive will have to remain on the external") may could be a big problem

Comment: @Aiace Me and my friends have done this in a different manner. And it worked without any problem when we connected it internally. But until someone confirms it . I opt not to comment on the topic

Comment: so we have just to wait that someone confirm that there are no problems if I follow your suggestion

Comment: @Aiace Yes, but according me it should work, I will update my answer when I am damn sure it works